# Trying to connect my website to phymyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I want to connect my website to phpmyadmin database but I am not able to do so.
When I echo `$insert_product`, it works fine meaning that it shows the data inserted, but the data is not uploading to the phpmyadmin database when I remove the echo

```
//connection to db

     <?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ecom");

    ?>



<!doctype html>
    <?php include("includes\db.php"); ?>

    <html>
    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Insert a Product</title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#3F3360">

    <form action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <table align="center"  width="1000" border="1" bgcolor="#566043">
      <tbody>
        <tr align="center">
          <td colspan="8">Insert here</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Product title</b></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="product_title" required/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Product Category</b></td>
          <td><select name="product_cat">
                <option>Select a Category</option>

                <?php $get_cats = "select * from categories";

        $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

        while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) 
        {

            $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];

        echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";    


        }
    ; ?>



            </select> 

            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Product brand</b></td>
          <td><select name="product_brand">
                <option>Select Brands</option>

                <?php $get_cats = "select * from categories";

        $get_brands = "select * from brands";

        $run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);

        while ($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)) 
        {

            $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
            $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];

        echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";    


        }
    ; ?>

            </select> 
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Product Image</td>
          <td><input type="file" name="product_image"</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Product Price</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="product_price"</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Product Description</td>
          <td><textarea name="product_desc" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Product keywords</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="product_keywords"</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td align="center" colspan="8" ><input type="submit" name="insert_post" value="Insert"</td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php
    // Inserting Data to Database
    if(isset($_POST['insert_post']))
    {
        $product_title =$_POST['product_title'];
        $product_cat =$_POST['product_cat'];
        $product_brand =$_POST['product_brand'];
        $product_price =$_POST['product_price'];
        $product_desc =$_POST['product_desc'];
        $product_keywords =$_POST['product_keywords'];



        $product_image =$_FILES['product_image']['name'];
        $product_image_tmp =$_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];

        move_uploaded_file ($product_image_tmp, "product_image/$product_image");

      $insert_product = "insert into products (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords) 
    values ('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";

      $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);

      if($insert_pro){

          echo "<script>alert('product instereted')</script>";
          echo "<script>window.open('insert_product.php', '_self')</script>";

          }


    }
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors coming from db.php? Are you sure you have a connection?

Comment: please refresh you `phpmyadmin`

Comment: done already not working even the js are not working

Comment: echo the query and then run directly in phpmyadmin.

Comment: what does db.php contain?  it looks like you have 2 connections, there's one on top of the page, I'm not sure what's on `db.php` post the content of tht file

Comment: Hi, firstly, just a correction of definition. PHPMyAdmin is a web front end for the database engine MySQL. What you really want is to connect your PHP to MySQL. Anyway, could you please include db.php for us? Remember to put placeholder text in place of sensitive information. This will allow us to get a bit of a better idea of how you are structuring your code and if there is anything in that file that is missing. Also, can you log in to phpmyadmin using the same password you use for your web app?

Also, before you continue to create SQL with raw data, please sanitise your inputs.

Comment: Unrelated to the question however this is important. As per my previous comment, by Sanitising your inputs, you stop anyone on your website from injecting javascript. Say I typed into an input the following line:
; DROP (SELECT DATABASE) //
That may drop the database (I'm not entirely certain I got the syntax correct and I will not check as I'm not aiding anyone in any SQL Injection attacks).
So please, read the following article.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: '<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ecom");?>'  
Actually this is my db.php file and it is external file

Comment: try using this code to connect `<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ecom";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{

 echo "Connection success";
}
?>` Tell me what results u get when running this page @RiShavSinha

Comment: Did u also check your error log?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Try using the code to connect but nothing happens i just enter the data click submit it goes back to the normal..
how to check error log i am using dreamweaver

Comment: it does not even print the message?

Comment: are you using xampp?

Comment: i am using wamp...it prints back the following page when i use echo
[link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AncmDH9ngMfWhFj_Eq7ICcHuxdU6)
this shows the connection in running right?